# Show that $G$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut}_{G-Set}(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

A problem from Aluffi's Algebra Chapter 0.

> Let $G$ be a group. Consider $G$ as a $G$-set, by acting with left-multiplication. Prove that $\operatorname{Aut}_{G-Set}(G)\cong G$.

What I have so far:

We are looking for all equivariant bijections from $G$ to itself, i.e. all bijections $\varphi\colon G\to G$ such that

$$(\forall g,a\in G)\quad\varphi(ga)=g\varphi(a)$$
It is easy to see that the map
$$\varphi_x\colon G\to G,\quad g\mapsto gx^{-1}$$
is an equivariant bijection for all $x\in G$.
So, we have a map
$$
\psi\colon G\to \operatorname{Aut}_{G-Set}(G),\quad x\mapsto\varphi_x
$$
It is clear that this map is an injective homomorphism. It is left to show that $\psi$ is surjective, and this is what I can't do.

Thanks.

Comment: So $G$ is a group? Is there anything else about it that we should know?

Comment: Yes, it is a group. And no, there is no further information. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $\varphi_x$ you can recover the value of $x$ by evaluating it at the identity and then taking the inverse. In other words the map $\varphi\mapsto \varphi(e)^{-1}$ is a candidate inverse for $\Psi$. All you have to do is prove that for any $\varphi\in \operatorname{Aut}_{G-Set}(G)$, the following holds:
$$\varphi=\varphi_{\varphi(e)^{-1}}$$
which is straightforward.

Comment: This is the inverse map $im(\psi)\to G$. But the main question is: why does any equivariant bijection $G\to G$ have the form of $\varphi_x$ for some $x\in G$?

Comment: @lanskey I edited to make it clearer.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks!

Comment: @lanskey you're welcome!